# Bottle: acessando a mesma sessão em diferentes dispositivos Canister

Tags: python-3.x, aplicação-web, session

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto a caráter de estudo e estou com um grande inconveniente.

Estou utilizando:

- astroid==2.0.4
- bottle==0.12.13
- canister==1.5.1
- colorama==0.4.0
- cymysql==0.9.12
- Cython==0.29
- isort==4.3.4
- lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
- mccabe==0.6.1
- PyJWT==1.6.4
- pylint==2.1.1
- six==1.11.0
- wrapt==1.10.11

Como podem ver utilizo canister para criar e manter minhas sessões, o problema que enfrento é o seguinte, ao inserir login e senha, realizar confirmação de existência e confirmação de dados no banco de dados e iniciar uma sessão, se eu acesso o meu utilizando o (ip do meu computador):8080 ele não me leva para a tela inicial, não me leva para a tela de login, me leva para meu dashboard, como se eu já tivesse logado naquele dispositivo, achei que talvez pudesse ser problema com minha rede ou algo assim, desta forma hospedei no pythonanywhere e continuei com mesmo problema.

```
from bottle import Bottle, TEMPLATE_PATH
from Data.SQL import MySQL
import os
import canister
from canister import session

# Diretorio base.
base_path = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/')
# Instancia da aplicacao.
app = Bottle()
# Path de configuracao.
app.config.load_config('{}/config/lobster.config'.format(base_path))
# Instalacao do plugin de sessoes.
app.install(canister.Canister())

# Instancia do banco de dados.
banco_mysql = MySQL()

from app.Controllers import *
```

Quando é realizada a consulta e os dados são validos são executados os seguintes métodos criando tanto as sessões quanto os cookies

```
def definir_cookie_login(self, usuario_id, nome, email, na, unidade):
    response.set_cookie('usuario_id', str(usuario_id))
    response.set_cookie('nome_usuario', str(nome))
    response.set_cookie('email', str(email))
    response.set_cookie('na', str(na))
    response.set_cookie('unidade', str(unidade))

def iniciar_sessao(self, usuario_id, nome, email, na, unidade):
    session.data['usuario_id'] = str(usuario_id)
    session.data['nome_usuario'] = str(nome)
    session.data['email'] = str(email)
    session.data['na'] = str(na)
    session.data['unidade'] = str(unidade)
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia? como posso fazer para que cada tentativa de acesso em um dispositivo diferente ou até mesmo em um navegador diferente seja criada uma nova sessão ao invés de acessar a que já está sendo usada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percebi que quando criava o `session.data` ele criava apenas um `session.data` para todas as sessões, como eu precisava de uma form apara diferênciar as sessões resolvi criar as chaves do `session.data` utilizando algo que diferência-se cada sessão e mesmo assim permitisse persistir a sessão, então utilizei o `session.sid` concatenado com as chaves que eu estava criando, não sei se esta é a forma mais pythonica (provavelmente não) ou a mais correta (muito provavelmente não), mas foi a forma como consegui resolver meu problema e agora está funcionando, fiz o deploy pelo [pythonanywhere.com](https://pythonanywhere.com). Testei em vários dispositivos e até o momento não tive problema com desempenho nem com sessões duplicadas, no primeiro momento pensei em utilizar o ip do cliente, porém `request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')` me fornece o ip local do cliente ou seja seria possivel ter duas pessoas acessando usando o ip 192.168.0.x ou 192.168.15.x etc...

O método que inicializa minha sessão ficou da seguinte forma:

```
def iniciar_sessao(self, usuario_id, nome, email, na, unidade):
    session.user = request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    session.data[session.sid+'usuario_id'] = str(usuario_id)
    session.data[session.sid+'nome_usuario'] = str(nome)
    session.data[session.sid+'email'] = str(email)
    session.data[session.sid+'na'] = str(na)
    session.data[session.sid+'unidade'] = str(unidade)
```

E para encerrar as sessões:

```
def encerrar_sessao(self):
    del session.data[session.sid+'usuario_id']
    del session.data[session.sid+'nome_usuario']
    del session.data[session.sid+'email']
    del session.data[session.sid+'na']
    del session.data[session.sid+'unidade']
    session.user = None
```

Se alguém souber de alguma forma mais prática (ou mais pythonica) podem compartilhar comigo, gostaria de melhorar meus códigos.

Caso a forma esteja correta, espero que ajude mais alguém.